# PSpice transient analysis failed to converge

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, pspice

I have the following schematic with 2 opamp. I have to do a transient analysis and eventually find the slew rate of the opamp. My simulation parameters are:

- Run to time: 1ms
- Step size: 1us

[image: schematics]

[image: error]

Any suggestions on how to fix it ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have PSpice, but here's a a couple generic SPICE suggestions.  (1) Try different opamps.  (2) Increase TR and TF of the pulse source.  (3) Add a small series resistor (10mohm to 100mohm) between the supply voltages and VCC/VEE nodes and also 100nF capacitors to ground on those nodes.

Comment: pay attention to a "ground" node at Vcc/Vee generation network, to the left of your schematic. Ref.: https://www.pspice.com/incorrect-ground-symbol-may-result-floating-node-or-convergence-problems

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. My problem coming from the wrong GND on the left of my schematic.
[Link](https://www.pspice.com/incorrect-ground-symbol-may-result-floating-node-or-convergence-problems)

Comment: You may have used your hands to fix it, but the insight came from [V.V.T's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527335/pspice-transient-analysis-failed-to-converge#comment1357849_527335). At any rate, you can check your answer.